# Примеры прилагательных с суффиксом "-лив-"

Tags: словообразование

Какие есть прилагательные с суффиксом "-лив-"?

Comment: В чём суть вопроса? Да, есть прилагательные с таким суффиксом: говорливый, дождливый. И что?

Answer (score 1):

суФФикс - пишется с ФФ даже латиницей)). А вопроса я тоже не наблюдаю.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, olya хочет, чтоб ей привели примеры.

Баловливый, беззаботливый, безрасчётливый, бережливый, беседливый, блошливый, блудливый, богобоязливый, бодливый, болтливый...

Comment: Баловливый - нет такого слова; беседливый - нет такого слова.

Comment: Есть такие слова.  "...отозвалась девушка и глянула на Суковатова тем милым, ласкающим взглядом, каким смотрит мать на баловливое, но милое дитя" (М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин).  " Азарий Иннокентьевич был человеком беседливым, интересным, научил, как кабанов искать, и отправил в аэропорт" (Сергей Алексеев).  "...но он чесался, как блошливый пудель, ― и эти кресла под ним беспрестанно двигались и беспрестанно будили меня своим шумом" (Н. С. Лесков).

Comment: Есть и в словарях